# import of python/django modules fails on debian vps

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi

debian vps with gigatux.
using django/python with mod_wsgi and im using virtualenvs as i hope to be hosting a few different sites which may well be at different levels.

im having an issue getting the site running, right now i can't even do a syncdb as it refuses to import the django package that is inside the site-packages folder

I've got the statement below in my django.wsgi file which is called from the wsgi config line in apache2/sites-available/default

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/shofty/virtualenvs/sitename/lib/python2.5/site-packages')
```

and i've got quite a few packages in that folder.

however syncdb won't run.

now ive installed django on the vps without forcing it into a virtualenv, then i can run syncdb. but syncdb fails on the import of modules in installedapps that are in the site-packages but not installed on the vps. so i know that that statement above isnt working.

i appreciate there may be a more specialised place to ask this question, i just dont know it. tell me what that is if you know somewhere where this will get answered. i've got two days getting this vps running and to be honest, im ready to give up.

Comment: Did you do a `source` on the virtualenv?

Comment: no which is a rather noob mistake to make!

Comment: done that, now it won't import postgresql_psycopg2, so maybe thats not the fix. not sure how to work out why it won't import modules from site-packages...

Answer (score 1):

Mixing up environments won't help.

Clearly some packages are installed in the bundled python and some other in the virtualenv.

My suggestion, **stick to virtualenv**

And work on the virtualenv, always, by `source /path/to/venv/bin/activate`

Within the wsgi file, **enable the virtualenv**. You do that not by importing its site_packages, but by asking the mod_wsgi to use *that* python. You do that by the following command:

```
activate_this = '/path/to/venv/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
```

Comment: that works well, thanks. one last thing i need to know is how you run syncdb on a virtualenv'd vps? im getting an error about psycopg2 not being a valid module

Comment: Virtualenv, by default falls back to the modules installed in the system wide python package, unless you have explicitly asked it not to. So, psycopyg2 should be available, if it is there in the system wide package. I suggest reinstalling the virtualenv from pip.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on getting debian, apache, django, mod_wsgi, and virtualenvs to play nicely a couple weeks ago. Looking at the template I made for our wsgi files I'm using both 'site.addsitedir' and 'sys.path.append' where 'site.addsitedir' points to the site_package and 'sys.path.append' points to a copy of the application on the host. Here is what the first part of the jinja2 template looks like for django.wsgi

```
import sys
import os
import site

site.addsitedir('{{ site_package }}')
sys.path.append('{{ local_source }}')
...
```

'local_source' is something like '/home/jdoe/my_project' and 'site_package' is something like '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages'.

I remember have to play around with it a bit, and I also remember an issue with 'django.wsgi' and 'settings.py' having to be in the same directory. I hope that helps.